# Okta Angular: Error: The 'post_logout_redirect_uri' parameter must be a Logout redirect URI

Tags: angular, okta

When I try to log out it displays this:

```
400
Bad Request
Your request resulted in an error. The 'post_logout_redirect_uri' parameter must be a Logout redirect URI in the client app settings: https://dev-81234586-admin.okta.com/admin/app/oidc_client/instance/0oa57yhuuyEUUMMqN5d7#tab-general
```

this is my configuration of application:

```
Sign-in redirect URIs 
Allow wildcard * in login URI redirect.
http://localhost:4200/callback

Sign-out redirect URIs 
http://localhost:4200/sign-out
```

this is my full URL:

```
https://dev-81234586.okta.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout?id_token_hint=eyJraWQiOiJUVlVDS0Fkdk1NNThHQzJEd2xSMkxDVVdZUHVJaEE0S0hJSWdrdWk0c2F3IiwiYWxnIjoiUlMyNTYifQ.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.0tu7_tGc3Q4iYgeFeNybj2w8arhn92rEPwgGCLEtX7UYjzApxcxO8q5-gs-Of5MnAsKX1Qisl0Wl11oUlGEMUXuvjcyR10JvY5aFQSbTQH0o1EFqiXeSiy61Bu01pa6s8doIkZa1yxozya2UuAttp4z4R3_V--QaVtJ-E7O1gmNOmEanW70hDB0lGroHh7tWZ6qV4eqni7EaAzJVQ-NesA-sVdeFwiy_1LmXzb2wkAohYn-aiwJT3go5kr27fXCgznnudAVuN6vJ8q6SCtjb5qJes7cDyGji9iFRCT9tMDsQJ5T78EyIdcocHUblVrxV5D_j2Ofe5fGKaaQBe99ruA&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200
```

At the end of URL I see this: `&post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200` I dont know if it has a relation with the problem

Answer (score 3):

Your configuration indicates that the `post_logout_redirect_uri` should be `http://localhost:4200/sign-out` but you are passing `http://localhost:4200` instead. 
Since the URLs do not match, Okta will not redirect you, since the sign out URL needs to be whitelisted.

Change the `post_logout_redirect_uri` parameter in you request to match the URL you have configured.

Comment: Thanks I jst changed the redirect url configuration in the app and worked

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your `post_logout_url` parameter in your request to `/logout` end-point has different URL, than configured for your application

Comment: but I have implemented `Sign-out redirect URIs 
http://localhost:4200/sign-out` as a log-out url, as far as I know it should redirects me to that url right ?